# How to set user language settings in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, internationalization

I use [tap-i18n](https://github.com/TAPevents/tap-i18n) to internationalize my website.

I want to let the user change the language of his/her choice.

I can change language on startup in a file `client/setLanguage.js`:

```
getUserLanguage = function () {
  return "fr";
};

Meteor.startup(function () {
  var language = getUserLanguage();

  TAPi18n.setLanguage(newLanguage).done(function () {
    console.log("language changed");
  }).fail(function (error_message) {
    console.log(error_message);
  });
});
```

but I want the language settings to follow what the user chose, instead of just setting the language manually on startup.

Should I just make a page with a form which can update language with

```
Meteor.users.update({ userId: userId }, { $set: { language: newLanguage } }
```

and just set

```
var newLanguage = Meteor.findOne(Meteor.userId()).language;
TAPi18n.setLanguage(newLanguage);
```

somewhere on the client?

I just think this code is a bit inadequate and is it effective to make a database call so often? Shouldn't I only set language on startup and on the settings page?

Answer (score 0):

The best way for user to choose language is to have select input at the top of the page:

[lang http://www.acclaro.com/assets/images/blog/Image/international%20website%20nav%20drop%20down.png](http://www.acclaro.com/assets/images/blog/Image/international%20website%20nav%20drop%20down.png)

You can set up an event for onChange the language select and save the default language:

```
Meteor.users.update({ userId: userId }, { $set: { language: newLanguage }});
TAPi18n.setLanguage(newLanguage);
```

If user leaves the page/app, you can then set his default language on startup and his default language is set up when he returns:

```
getUserLanguage = function () {
  var userLang = 'fr';
  if (Meteor.user()) {
    userLang = Meteor.user().language
  }
  return userLang;
};

Meteor.startup(function () {
  var language = getUserLanguage();

  TAPi18n.setLanguage(language).done(function () {
    console.log("language changed");
  }).fail(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

But you have to publish/subscribe to the user data (language):

```
//null parameter will cause automatic publish, you don't need to subscribe
Meteor.publish(null, function() {
  return Meteor.users.find(
    { _id: this.userId },
    { fields: { language: 1 }}
  );
});
```